# 2-loop $\phi^4$ at finite temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, temperature

When evaluating diagrams that contribute to the 2-loop effective potential $V_{eff}$ in $\lambda \phi^4 $ theory at finite temperature one has to calculate diagrams of such type

[image]

which equals to

$$\sum_n \sum_m \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{d^3 q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{(k^2 + (2\pi \theta n)^2 + m^2) (q^2 + (2\pi \theta m)^2 + m^2) ((k+q)^2 + (2\pi \theta (n+m))^2 + m^2)}$$

where $\theta$ is a temperature.

I wonder how to calculate such diagrams - how to sum this. It doesn't look as easy as in 1-loop approximation.

Comment: There are many techniques used to evaluate loop integrals; I'd suggest starting with the book, *Feynman Integral Calculus* by Smirnov. It covers many methods not presented in standard QFT textbooks, including Baikov's method and evaluation by differential equations.